# Процентное соотношение по строке

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Как заменить значение в таблице (файл csv) или добавить столбцы с процентным соотношением

исходная таблица в штуках по дням

| Данные | Яблоко | киви |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01.02.2022 | 5 | 8 |
| 02.02.2022 | 6 | 9 |
| 03.02.2022 | 7 | 10 |

выходные данные - таблица в процентах по строке

| Данные | Яблоко_процент | киви_процент |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01.02.2022 | 38 | 62 |
| 02.02.2022 | 40 | 60 |
| 03.02.2022 | 41 | 58 |

Comment: О какой таблице речь? Каков формат входных данных?

Comment: Сумма по строке 5+8= 13 соответственно яблоко это 5/13, киви 8/13 в процентах

Comment: Всё ещё непонятно, каков конкретный формат входных данных

Comment: Входные данные dataframe datetimeindex яблоко non-null int64, киви non-null int64

Comment: Мне надо в Python

Comment: Есть csv файл. Индекс дата и 2 столбца с int данными. Мне надо добавить столбцы с процентами или дата фрейм преобразовать в процентное соотношение к сумме по строке

Comment: В чем заключается вопрос? "Мне надо" это не вопрос. Если надо - делай.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Ваш комментарий очень помог

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видимо, речь всё же про `Pandas`, раз упоминается датафрейм. Ну, тогда всё просто:

```py
df = df.div(df.sum(axis=1), axis=0)
df.columns = [f'{col}_процент' for col in df.columns]
```

- делим столбцы на суммы по строкам, тут главное правильно значения `axis=` угадать
- переименовываем столбцы

Comment: Спасибо большое